# Where to place PHP for shortcodes

Tags: php, shortcode

My custom plugin is broken into two parts: a frontend.php and admin.php for loading code conditionally. Here is a rough outline of the code:

```
<?php
/*
My plugin info here
*/

if (is_admin()) {
  include_once('admin.php');
} else {
  include_once('frontend.php');
}

?>
```

I have written several shortcodes for use in pages and posts. In which file (admin.php or frontend.php) should code related to shortcodes be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcodes are processed on display so the code must be available on the front end when the shortcode is processed. Superficially, that means `frontend.php`.

I have never tried to split shortcode code in this way. You may have trouble splitting it off from the backend. The `add_shortcode` function is in [`wp-includes/shortcodes.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/shortcodes.php) which loads for both back and front, suggesting that it is at least possible that it is needed on the back end. I'd have to run some experiments...

Comment: I am testing it now. I put the entire shortcode-related code into frontend.php (the handler function as well as the `add_shortcode` line) and it seems to be working as expected. I will test some more later but I think it can stay there.